# Mirasvit SeoContent conflict with customer address

Tags: magento2, extensions

I am using magento version 2.2.5. **Mirasvit SeoContent** extension version 2.0.92.

**Problem**: When the customer is login, the Customer not able to enter the address. Because `magento225/customer/address/new/` or `magento225/customer/address/new/edit/` is not opening. When I click on it, it will redirect to the `magento225/customer/account` page. I spent more than 10 hours to find out the reason.

I **disabled all extensions** that time address URL is opening and working fine. So I unable to extension one by one. That time I came to know that this ***Mirasvit SeoContent*** Extension creates a problem to open customer address URL.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

**EDIT** :
Both functionality are important. We need SeoContent Extension and also want to save customer address. So Can't disable extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful extension to help you find conflicts

https://github.com/magefan/module-conflict-detector

But in a nutshell one extension will need to extend the other instead of core magento.  Providing they overide different methods this is fine.

Of they are overriding the same method you are going to have to manually edit the one being used and merge logic.

Although rereading your question. Are you having a problem with a single extension or two conflicting extensions? Rememering that an extension is any functionality that builds upon the core. Have you reached out to the extension dev?

Comment: I installed this extension. But nothing found related to mirasvit seocontent extension. And there is no other extension makes problem. When I disable this mirasvit seocontent extension, everything works fine. Customer able to save its address. But when this extension is unable, address/edit or address/new url is not opening @Dominic

Comment: I dont know what is the issue. Because both modules( seocontent and customer) have different functionality. Thats why I am confuse..

Answer (score 0):

I found problematic part. Go to this path : 
`app/code/Mirasvit/SeoContent/Plugin/Frontend/Framework/App/Action/PutDefaultMetaPlugin.php`

Problem is with this function : `public function afterDispatch($subject, $response){}`
 Line no 48. Here I put this condition and `customer/address/new/` , `magento225/customer/address/new/edit/`, `customer/address/edit/id/3/`  url are working fine.

Code :

```
public function afterDispatch($subject, $response)
    {
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if (strpos($url, 'customer/account/') == TRUE OR strpos($url, 'customer/address/') == TRUE) {
            return $response;
        }
// rest code are same
.......
.......

}
```